# How to detect is data provider run in parallel mode

Tags: testng

I have data provider with parallel and without it

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] scale() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {0.33},
                {0.5}
        };
    }
```

Does TestNG contain listener(like IInvokedMethodListener) where I can view parallel = true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: listener `IDataProviderListener`

here is the complete solution:

```
class CustomListener implement IDataProviderListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod dataProviderMethod, ITestNGMethod method, ITestContext iTestContext) {
        boolean isParallel = dataProviderMethod.isParallel();
    }

}
```